# Parsing "true" / "false" in Java

Tags: java, parsing, text-processing

What's the utility method that parses a boolean String properly? By properly I mean

```
"true" => true
"false" => false
"foo" => error
```

The parse methods in java.lang.Boolean are dodgy - they don't distinguish "false" from "foo". Anything else in Java libraries (or Guava, or Commons Lang) that does it properly?

Yes it's just be a couple lines, I just rather not write *any* line that I shouldn't have to. :-)

Comment: There's a point where reusing code/libraries is just going too far. This is one of those times.

Comment: I think you'll have to write a couple of lines. :)

Comment: not sure anything exists that throws an error on no match.  You'll probably spend more time looking for a solution than writing you own Booleans.parse((String)str,(boolean)strictMatch).

Comment: Sometimes (but not always) writing a couple of lines is better than bringing on dependency on a third party library. Android anyone?

Comment: It is a ridiculous question, of course :) I asked because I saw Boolean.valueOf used in code today, and was surprised when I looked at its code. An unnecessary bug waiting to happen! I can only think it reflects its age in the JDK, hopefully it wouldn't have been written that way these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Boolean Utils form apache commons :

[Boolean Utils API](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Converts a String to a Boolean
>   throwing an exception if no match
>   found.
>
> null is returned if there is no match.
>
> BooleanUtils.toBoolean("true",
>   "true", "false")  = true
>   BooleanUtils.toBoolean("false",
>   "true", "false") = false

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to BooleanUtils. I think [toBooleanObject("true")](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html#toBooleanObject(java.lang.String)) fits the bill. It doesn't throw an error but it does return null which will still catch the problem (when unboxed).

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( "true".equalsIgnoreCase(yourString) )
      return true;
else if ( "false".equalsIgnoreCase(yourString) )
      return false;
else
      throw new Exception();
```

There's not one.

Comment: @Alexander -- Thanks :-) Probably because the OP did not want to "write any line"

Comment: I think an `equalsIgnoreCase` would be more appropriate, no?

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, this question is ridiculous. Yes, there are ways to do it built in (the Boolean utils API Apache Fan mentioned). But you're going out of your way to do something in a fancy way at the cost of A) productivity (stop wasting your time, write the three lines of code), and B) readability. What's easier to read:

```
if( "true".equals(myString) )
```

or

```
if( BooleanUtils.toBoolean(myString, "true", "false") )
```

I'd go for the first one every time. Even better, use the IgnoreCase option for the string comparison. The toBoolean is case sensitive, so "True" would actually throw an exception. Awesome! That's really useful!

Comment: -1 for the strawman comparison; the choice is between the BooleanUtils call or something like @Kal's example. Neither is pretty. Both get the job done. As you say, it wasn't the most serious question. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about the very simple:

EDIT: or am I missing the point...

```
boolean isTrue (String s) {
  return theString.toLowerCase().equals("true");
}
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to swap the comparison. This will throw a NPE if s is null.

Comment: OP wants only "true" and "false" as valid options.  In your case any string is a valid option.